# This message was sent to {{toAddress}} because you subscribed to Tips & Recommendations on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

This was the mail I got from StackOverflow about jobs. Besides the `{{toAddress}}` and `{{recommendedJobs}}` problem, none of the links are clickable.[image]

Comment: It probably is a dup. This was received at 2:31am IST, eight hours ago.

Comment: Ah, probably is then.

Comment: I can confirm that you were in the initial batch mentioned in the other question. Sorry :(